# Append to txt file several readings coming from different functions python3 opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, append, triangulation

I am getting error from my code.
Basically, I have some function called Triangulate

> tringulate = cv2.triangulatePoints(projection_matrix_1,
> projection_matrix_2, projection_points1, projection_points_2)

The function gives me some output like this

```
[[ X1 X2 X3 ... Xn]
 [ Y1 Y2 Y3 ... Yn]
 [ Z1 Z2 Z3 ... Zn]
 [ W1 W2 W3 ... Wn]]
```

I am also having another function for detecting the descriptors from some camera frame.

> kps, desc = self.detector.detectAndCompute(self.image, None)

The output of the desc is like this

```
here [[ 97  93   2 ..., 255  63   1]
 [ 64 141   1 ..., 123 255  62]
 [ 97  29  14 ..., 253 127   3]
 ..., 
 [218 233 131 ..., 253 255  15]
 [  1 237 143 ..., 127 255  15]
 [ 97 253  13 ..., 176 255   3]]

here [[ 64 141   0 ..., 123 255  31]
 [ 97  29  78 ..., 253 127   1]
 [  0  13   0 ..., 123 255  30]
 ..., 
 [ 97 253  15 ..., 255 255   3]
 [ 64 141   1 ...,   2  16  48]
 [  1 237 143 ..., 255 102  15]]
```

The output of both functions is changing whenever new reading is coming. The readings are coming from robot movement. It is recorded in rosbag.

Now I want to write a txt file which will have.

```
X1 Y1 Z1 W1 desc1 X2 Y2 Z2 W2 desc2  ... Xn Yn Zn Wn descn
```

In which x y z w are outputs from first reading of triangulate and desc1 is output from first reading of desc function .. etc till it finishes.

I was able to take the readings of triangulate and add it without any issues from this code

```
            f = open("11.txt", "w")  # Erases the file content.
            f.close()
```

> here exists both functions

```
            f = open("11.txt", "a")
            f.write(','.join(str(v) for v in self.tringulate.T.flat) + '\n')
            f.close()
```

I was able to save X1 Y1 Z1 W1 X2 Y2 Z2 W2 but without the desc1 ... desc2 ...etc

Any advice please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC can you tell me what exactly is needed in the example above?